# z3py: Retrieve branching conditions from z3 formula

Tags: z3, z3py

Let's say I have a z3py program like this one:

```
import z3


a = z3.Int("a")
input_0 = z3.Int("input_0")
output = z3.Int("output")

some_formula = z3.If(a < input_0, 1, z3.If(a > 1, 4, 2))

s = z3.Solver()

s.add(output == some_formula)

s.check()
m = s.model()
print(m)
```

Is there an elegant way for me to retrieve the branching conditions from `some_formula`?
So get a list like `[a < input_0, a > 1]`. It should work for arbitrarily deep nesting of if expressions.

I know there is some way to use cubes, but I am not able to retrieve more than two cube expressions. I am not sure how to configure the solver.

My ultimate goal is to force the solver to give me different outputs based on the constraints I push and pop. The constraints are the set of conditions I have inferred from this formula.

Answer (score 0):

You can print the cubes using:

```py
for cube in s.cube():
    print cube
```

But this isn't going to really help you. For your example, it prints:

```
[If(a + -1*input_0 >= 0, If(a <= 1, 2, 4), 1) == 1]
[Not(If(a + -1*input_0 >= 0, If(a <= 1, 2, 4), 1) == 1)]
```

which isn't quite what you were looking for.

The easiest way to go about your problem would be to directly walk down the AST of the formula yourself, and grab the conditions as you walk along the expressions. Of course, Z3 AST is quite a hairy object (pun intended!), so this will require quite a bit of programming. But reading through the constructors (`If`, `Var` etc.) in this file can get you started: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/z3py_8py_source.html

Answer (score 0):

Alright,thanks @alias! I came up with a custom version, which gets the job done. If someone knows a more elegant way to do this, please let me know.

```
import z3


a = z3.Int("a")
input_0 = z3.Int("input_0")
output = z3.Int("output")

some_formula = z3.If(a < input_0, 1, z3.If(a > 1, 4, 2))
nested_formula = z3.If(some_formula == 1, 20, 10)

s = z3.Solver()

s.add(output == some_formula)

s.check()
m = s.model()
print(m)


def get_branch_conditions(z3_formula):
    conditions = []
    if z3.is_app_of(z3_formula, z3.Z3_OP_ITE):
        # the first child is usually the condition
        cond = z3_formula.children()[0]
        conditions.append(cond)
    for child in z3_formula.children():
        conditions.extend(get_branch_conditions(child))
    return conditions


conds = get_branch_conditions(some_formula)
print(conds)
conds = get_branch_conditions(nested_formula)
print(conds)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this'll always do the right thing; and in particular it doesn't seem to handle the case `If (If(A, B, C), D, E)` correctly. But it all of course depends on what you mean by "branching condition" and your particular use case.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I was mostly interested in grabbing the individual if conditions so I can add them as constraints for the solver further down the line. I edited my original statement. In this case, I was okay with returning nested statements in the condition as is. I can try and see If I can come up with a more fine-grained version.

Comment: Actually, I gave this some thought and I am not sure how it does not cover this case. What is a better way to represent these conditions? Or what is an adversarial example?

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by a branching condition. Since you haven't really formally defined what that means, it's not possible to argue what would be a good algorithm to find them. One can imagine branching condition to be pure boolean constants or variables only, for instance. It really depends on what your eventual goal is.